# Handling test data in a SVM with kernel built from scratch in Python without ML-related libraries

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I am working on a SVM classifier and I cannot use any ML-related libraries. I did quite well with the non-kernel version, but stuck in training a advanced one with kernels.

Here are my codes so far:

```
class my_SVM():
    def __init__(self, lr, it, lamb,tag,kernel):
        self.lr=lr #learning rate
        self.it=it #number of iterations
        self.lamb=lamb #lambda parameter
        self.tag=tag #this SVM is used to distinguish whether label==tag
        self.kernel=kernel #list of kernels 
    def fit(self, X,Y):
        self.X=self.K(X)
        self.Y=Y        
        self.m, self.n=self.X.shape #X:input, m:rows, n:columns
        #initiate the weight and bias
        self.w=np.zeros(self.n)
        self.b=0

        #implementing gradient descent algorithm
        for i in range(self.it):
            self.upd()     
    def upd(self):
        #label encoding
        y_label=np.where(self.Y==tag,1,-1) #in SVM the label is  -1 and 1
        #build gradients: dw, db
        for index, x_i in enumerate(self.X):
            
            condition=y_label[index]*(np.dot(x_i, self.w) - self.b)>=1
            if(condition):
                dw=2*self.lamb*self.w
                db=0
            else:
                dw=2*self.lamb*self.w-np.dot(x_i,y_label[index])
                db=y_label[index]
        
            self.w=self.w-self.lr*dw
            self.b=self.b-self.lr*db
    def pred(self,X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w) - self.b
    
    #kernels
    def linear(self,x,y):
        return np.dot(x.T,y)
    def polynomial(self,x,y):
        degree=2
        return (np.dot(x.T,y) + float(1))**degree
    def rbf(self,x,y):
        gamma=10
        return np.exp(-1.0*gamma*np.dot(np.subtract(x,y).T,np.subtract(x,y)))
    def K(self,X):
        kernels = {
            "linear":self.linear,
            "rbf":self.rbf,
            "poly":self.polynomial
            }        
        K = np.zeros([X.shape[0],X.shape[0]])
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            for j in range(X.shape[0]):
                K[i,j] = kernels[self.kernel](X[i],X[j])
        print(K.shape)
        return K
```

The training set is 50000 one-dimentional vectors, each with 784 elements. Doesn't it mean that the w I get finally has a shape of 50000? If so, let's move to the test set, which contains 10000 one-dimentional vectors, each with 784 vectors. Apparently it can't be directly put into the pred function. Then what should I do?